# How to make nested queries in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

i have a realm:

```
class Train: RLMObject {
    dynamic var stationDeparture: Station?
    dynamic var trainId = 0
    dynamic var route = RLMArray(objectClassName: Route.className())
    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "trainId"
    }
}
class Route: RLMObject {
    dynamic var numberInRoute = 0
    dynamic var station: Station?
    var owners: [Train] {
        return linkingObjectsOfClass("Train", forProperty: "Route") as! [Train]
    }
}
class Station: RLMObject {
    dynamic var code = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "code"
    }
    dynamic var relatedStations = RLMArray(objectClassName: Station.className())
}
```

I tried to get all trains for station and station's related stations in `class Train: RLMObject` for `dynamic var stationDeparture: Station?`. At first i made a String from codes of related stations and then make a query using "IN" in predicate.

This function works, ugly but it works !:

```
func trainsForDepartureStation (station: Int) -> RLMResults? {
    let stations = Station.objectsWhere("code == \(station)")
    let related = stations.lastObject() as! Station
    if related.relatedStations.count > 0 {
        var st = ""
        st += "{\(station)"
        for id in 0...related.relatedStations.count-1 {
            st += ", \(related.relatedStations[id].code)"
        }
        st += "}"
        let trains = Train.objectsWhere("stationDeparture.code IN \(st)")

        return trains

    } else {
        let trains = Train.objectsWhere("stationDeparture.code == \(station)")
        return trains
    }
}
```

But when i tried to do the same to get the trains with the all stations in all routes of train, it does not work.

`let trains = Train.objectsWhere("ANY route.station.relatedStations.code IN \(st)")`

The mistake is:

```
'Invalid predicate', reason: 'Predicate with ANY modifier must compare a KeyPath with RLMArray with a value'
```

How to make nested query for this issue ?
I'm new to swift, objective-с and realm (

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to break down that query into multiple queries, as you may have guessed. First off, though, let's just refactor `trainsForDepartureStation()` to better understand what it's currently doing:

```
func trainsForDepartureStation(station: Int) -> RLMResults? {
  let stations = Station.objectsWhere("code == \(station)")
  if let related = stations.lastObject() as? Station where related.relatedStations.count > 0 {
    return Train.objectsWhere("stationDeparture IN %@", related.relatedStations)
  } else {
    return Train.objectsWhere("stationDeparture.code == \(station)")
  }
}
```

Ok, so now let's change this to return the "trains with the all stations in all routes of train":

```
func trainsForDepartureStation(station: Int) -> RLMResults? {
  let stations = Station.objectsWhere("code == \(station)")
  if let related = stations.lastObject() as? Station where related.relatedStations.count > 0 {
    let allRelatedStations = Station.objectsWhere("relatedStations IN %@", related.relatedStations)
    let allRelatedRoutes = Route.objectsWhere("station IN %@", allRelatedStations)
    return Train.objectsWhere("ANY route IN %@", allRelatedRoutes)
  } else {
    let allRelatedRoutes = Route.objectsWhere("station == %@", stations.lastObject() as! Station)
    return Train.objectsWhere("ANY route IN %@", allRelatedRoutes)
  }
}
```

Comment: this work for routes with only related stations, how to concatenate this results if routes exist both for parent station and related stations ?

Comment: combine those two queries with an "OR" to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 mistake, this part:

```
    let allRelatedStations = Station.objectsWhere("relatedStations IN %@", related.relatedStations)
    let allRelatedRoutes = Route.objectsWhere("station IN %@", allRelatedStations)
```

should be replaced by:

```
    let allRelatedRoutes = Route.objectsWhere("station IN %@", related.relatedStations)
```

because allRelatedStations did not fetch related station, but only parent stations again )